# nodejs Route.get() not requiring callback functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I have trying to run the server using locallydb and on the server side, I have got this code here... The login file is in the main directory. and I get the following error: If any one can help...

```
  Error  C:\Users\user\Desktop\projectApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:196
            throw new Error(msg);
            ^

    Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
        at Route.(anonymous function) [as get] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\projectApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:196:15)
        at EventEmitter.app.(anonymous function) [as get] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\projectApp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:481:19)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\projectApp\server.js:7:6)
        at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
        at Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
        at run (node.js:348:7)
```

**Server.js**

```
     var express = require('express');
        var login = require('./login');
        express()
            .set('view engine', 'ejs')
            .use(express.static('./public'))
            .use(login.routes)
            .get('*',login.required, function (req, res) {
                res.render('index',{
                    user: login.safe(req.user)
                });
                }).listen(3000);

**Login.js**


   var passport = require('passport');
    var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');


    var LocallyDB = require('locallydb');
    var db = new LocallyDB('./.data');
    var users = db.collection('users');

    var crypto = require('crypto');

    function hash (password) {
        return crypto.createHash('sha512').update(password).digest('hex');
    }

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
        var user = users.where({ username: username, passwordHash: hash(password) }).items[0];

        if (user) {
            done(null, user);
        } else {
            done(null, false);
        }
    }));

    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, user.cid);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function (cid, done) {
        done(null, users.get(cid));
    });


    var router = require('express').Router();
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // Login Page
    router.use(bodyParser.json()); // API
    router.use(require('cookie-parser')());
    router.use(require('express-session')({
        secret: 'p7r6uktdhmcgvho8o6e5ysrhxmcgjfkot7r6elu5dtjt7lirfyj',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true
    }));
    router.use(passport.initialize());
    router.use(passport.session());

    router.get('/login', function (req, res) {
        res.render('login');
    });

    router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/login'
    }));

    exports.routes = router;
        enter code here
        enter code here
        enter code here
```

Comment: `login.required` doesn't seem to be defined in the exports in your login.js file, hence you're passing `undefined` to `get()` as the second argument.

Comment: you mean? return module.exports;

Comment: You have `exports.routes`, which means you can do `login.routes`, but there's no `exports.required`, which means `login.required` would be `undefined`

Comment: Thank you, was a great help!!!